# Common name of Disjunctive Normal Form where all clauses are pairwise disjunct

Tags: boolean-algebra, disjunctive-normal-form

A boolean formula is in *Disjunctive Normal Form* if it is a disjunction of conjunction of literals. Yet, this definition allows, that two of the conjunction clauses share models, i.e. there are interpretations for the variables, that both clauses evaluate to TRUE.

What is the name of the Disjunctive Normal Form, that does not allow this - where $c_a \vee c_b = false$ for all pairs of clauses?

A special case of this form is the Canonical Disjunctive Normal Form, but others may exist also.

In German text books I found the name "Disjunkte Disjunktive Normal Form" (Disjunct Disjunctive Normal Form) DDNF* - yet I did not find it in any English text books.

*I currently write a term paper and would like to use standard names, rather than make them up. I would be happy, if the answer includes at least one reference that indicates, the term is used like that.*

* [Klaus Gotthard, 2001: Grundlagen der Informationstechnik, p.77]